# SonarQube: No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration

Tags: sonarqube

I'm a SonarQube newbie. I'm running analysis in eclipse via sonar-eclipse-plugin. But on remote server, it displays:

> No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available
>   section is the configuration

How can I see the results of the analysis on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you have [provisioned your project](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Provisioning+Projects) to be able to make a local analysis in Eclipse.

- **Local analyses** (like what happens in Eclipse) don't push data to the server - they are used to "preview" the quality of your code
- **Regular analyses** do push the results to the server. You run such an analysis with Maven, SonarQube Runner, Ant, Gradle, Jenkins, ...

So if you want to see the results inside SonarQube Web application, just a regular analysis. Everything is explained in ["Analyzing Source Code" documentation section](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code).

Comment: Is there any way for eclipse to push the results to the server?

Comment: No, this is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario : I have analyzed one sub-module of this project in different project key. The error is `sonar module already part of project`.

How to detect : I use `maven` sonar client and there is one INFO log before `Reactor Summary`

```
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 35ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:32770/dashboard/index/test.test.test
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://localhost:32770/api/ce/task?id=AVoshDlt_7pTduMM9HHB
[INFO] Task total time: 13.621 s
```

Just goto `More about the report processing` link, you will find the reason.