# SonarQube: Jenkins analysis is not pushed to sonar server says No analysis has been performed since creation

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, maven-3

Coming from issue:[SonarQube: No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091844/sonarqube-no-analysis-has-been-performed-since-creation-the-only-available-sec)

I am doing this from jenkins and I am getting the same result. In fact I ran the same jenkins job with another branch and it made a project in Sonar. I cloned the branch in the job and pushed it into a new branch and ran the same job with the branch name changed and it gave me this error when i clicked on the link in jenkins build log.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my project 'com.test.af:af-app'

Try to check the project on SonarQube -
http://sqhost:9000/sonar/dashboard/index?id=com.test.af%3Aaf-app

.. this should give you the same error that you are seeing in the analysis log. "No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration"

You can fix this by deleting this project entry from SQ database using web api - 
http://sqhost:9000/sonar/api/projects/destroy?id=com.test.af:af-app

Now re run the analysis.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need setup Sonar Runner too

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Runner

Then try again