# Publishing Sonar analysis on SonarQube Dashboard

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

We have Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

```
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600
```

I have installed SonarQube Plugin in my eclipse and have configured the SonarQube Server. Tested the Server connection in Eclipse.

```
Windows>Preferences>Sonar>Servers. Connection is successful.
```

I am able to associate my project to Sonar in eclipse and get the report locally.

After fixing the violated issues , Is there a way we can publish the new report from our Local to the SonarQbe server dashboard.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube: No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091844/sonarqube-no-analysis-has-been-performed-since-creation-the-only-available-sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you appear to be using an old version of the plugin; the most recent version of [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) has not yet re-established the connected experience (although that's coming soon). You may be interested in upgrading because SonarLint checks your code as you work; there's no longer a need to trigger the analysis. This way, issues are brought to your attention immediately instead of your having to remember to look for them.

Now to your question: there is not a way to push your updated results from Eclipse directly into the SonarQube platform; you'll need to perform a full analysis. Keep in mind that in-IDE analysis runs most but not all rules. I.e. you're not going to get issues in Eclipse from the rule about too-low coverage thresholds, for instance. Ditto duplicatons. Those are only run as part of the full analysis.

Comment: I tried using SonarLint but it has limited functionalities as you said , Am waiting for the upcoming versions to "link" SonarLint with an existing SonarQube server instance. Thanks for your response as of now I modified our build.xml to use sonar-java and run the analysis and push the results.